# how to display an image using xslt

Tags: image, xslt

I have the following code

```
<xsl:template name="toggle">
        <xsl:param name="target"/>
        <xsl:param name="show"/>
            <input type="image" src="glass.png" /> 
                <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
                  toggle('<xsl:value-of select="$target"/>','<xsl:value-of select="$show"/>');
                </xsl:attribute>
            </input>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to add an external image which is not part of xml file. I want to replace my Submit button with an image. 
When using the above code I am unable to get the image as output.
Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Well it already looks like you're doing what you need to. You didn't mention what else you require, or what's not working.

Comment: Sorry about it. I am unable to get the image as the output.

Comment: I suggest using a `button` HTML element with an `IMG` inside.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what HTML you want to generate?

If you do, then tell us.

If you don't, then you have an HTML problem, not an XSLT problem.

Never try to write code in XSLT until you know what output HTML you want it to produce. Actually, I think it was Dijkstra who said you should never start writing any program until you know what output you want it to produce. A good principle. When applied to XSLT, remember that the output in this sense is an HTML document, not a screen displayed by the browser.

Comment: I am displaying the output as HTML only. My output is table. In which one column contains a submit button, so I replace that button with an image.

Comment: So attach the HTML you want to the question, and we can tell you what you need to do